# SearchForm is not shown in category.html

Tags: python, django

SearchForm is not shown in detail.html.
I wrote in views.py

```
def top(request):
    content = POST.objects.order_by('-created_at')[:5]
    form = SearchForm()

    return render(request,'top.html',{'content':content,'form':form})

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Detail
    template_name = 'detail.html'
    form = SearchForm()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

in category.html

```
<div class="search_box">
            <form action='/app/search/' method="POST">
                <table>
                {{ form.as_table }}
                </table>
                <button class="btn btn-secondary search" type="submit">SEARCH</button>
              {% csrf_token %}
            </form>
        </div>
div>
                        <h2>{{ object.title }}</h2>
                        <a href="{% url 'detail' content.pk %}">SHOW DETAIL</a>
                </div>
```

I think if I wrote DetailView class like top method which is `return render(request,'top.html',{'content':content,'form':form})`,I can show SearchForm() in detail.html.But DetailView class is generic view, so i cannot understand how I can read SearchForm() in DetailView class.I wrote context['search_form'] = SearchForm() but form is not shown.How should I fix this?What is wrong in my codes?

Comment: But you *haven't* written that line adding the form to the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Detail
    template_name = 'detail.html'
    form_class = SearchForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = self.form_class
        return context
```